# Using function to count banned words in C#

Tags: c#

So I've been trying and trying to get this script to work, but it's been a pain in the backside. Basically I want to check the sentence, to see if it contains banned words. And if that one given sentence contains more than 3 words (equal to, or more) then I want it to tell me so I can send an alert.

What I have so far:

```
public bool CheckSentence(string Message)
    {
        var count = 0;

        foreach (WordFilter Filter in this._filteredWords.ToList())
        {
            if (Message.Contains(Filter.Word) && Filter.IsSentence)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count >= 3;

    }
```

I am then trying to grab that, and if the sentence does contain more than 3 it will alert the person:

```
if (PlusEnvironment.GetGame().GetChatManager().GetFilter().CheckSentence(Message.ToLower()))
        {
            Session.SendNotification("Something you've said has made our ears tingle! ");
        }
```

But I feel like I'm going wrong somewhere, like it's not actually reading the sentence and counting how many times a banned word has been used.

The string is `Message`, the list of banned words is the `Filter.Word` and since I don't want all words (as my filter replaces other words with ***) to be included in the sentence filter, I've also added a column to the table `Filter.IsSentence` (1 or 0). This will check to see if the word is in the filter, and if it's also included to be the "IsSentence" filter.

From the script I have above, I feel like it's not actually counting how many banned words is in the string? Let's say my string is:

`Join this website today, free credits and much more! www.site.com`
In the database I would have the following words added:

```
join, website, free, credits, .com, www.
```

Out of those words, only `join, website, free and credits` will be checked if they're included in the sentence. Since there is 4 banned words in the one sentence (AND they're also `IsSentence`) second lot of code to run to send them a notification.

Comment: @PeterDennisBartok if you read it, you'll see that it's requesting the function VIA: `Message.ToLower()`

Answer (score 1):

So you have a list of words which are grouped as offensive/bad words. and you need to take count of those words in the given input sentence, As of now you ware used `.Contains()` actually this is not efficient to count the number of occurrence. I would like to split the sentence into words and the count the matching words each time. The modified method signature as per your requirement will be like this:

```
public bool CheckSentence(string messageText)
{
    var count = 0;
    string[] wordsInMessage = messageText.Split(new char[]{' ',','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (WordFilter Filter in this._filteredWords.ToList())
    {
       count += wordsInMessage.Count(x=> x == Filter.Word);            
    }

    return count >= 3;
}
```

Comment: Will the `Session.SendNotification`, I believe that `return count >= 3;` means that it'll return true if the count is or above 3?

Comment: I think this has actually fixed my code, I will test it now and let you know.

Comment: @Liam : yes, the method `CheckSentence` will return true if the count is greater than `3` or else it will be false. You can make a try and let me know any more updates if needed

Comment: It works great, although it only reads words that are spaced apart, so this will work: `JOIN GooGLe | × ,,. ¬ hiring HOteL , it is ++ free ,, community`

Comment: Where as, it won't work if I remove the space after `HOteL ,`

Comment: Cool... You can use character array inside the `Split` if you need to perform split based on multiple characters, see the updates in the post

Comment: @un-lucky I know you rejected my edit, but it really will fail if someone writes a "bad" word with uppercase character.

Comment: Okay, so now what about when I use:
`JOIN GooGle | × ,,. ¬ hiring !HOteL, it is ++ !!free!! ,, ..!community;;+_` banned words being "joined, hiring, hotel, free, community" it will work where I use whitespaces or , but not if I put ! or other things infront or behind.

Comment: @PeterDennisBartok the code works since it `ToLower()` it

Comment: @PeterDennisBartok: the reason behind that rejected edit is this, see the calling of the method in the op's code ie., `CheckSentence(Message.ToLower())`, So the input to our function is already Lower-cased sentence, Then what is the significance for converting it again to lower?

Comment: @un-lucky You're right. I apologize, my bad. My window wasn't wide enough and the ToLower was to the right so I missed it.

Comment: So the code above works, although it's not considering special chars such as ! and ;, so if I wrap the word around them, the user can bypass. I want it to search through the sentence regardless of how the words are wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation according to your example, it is giving me the correct output, you can check the SS of the output.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("join");
            list.Add("website");
            list.Add("free");
            list.Add("credit");
            list.Add("www.");
            list.Add(".com");

            var count = 0;

            string Message = "Join this website today, free credits and much more! www.site.com";

            foreach (var Filter in list)
            {
                if (Message.ToLower().Contains(Filter))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Filter);
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count>=3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nTRUE");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nFALSE");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: This is not what I'm using this application for. I'm implementing the code based off what I've posted.